# django/tastypie urls used within views

Tags: django, django-urls, tastypie

These are my urls:

```
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(UserResource())
v1_api.register(CategoryResource())

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/$', views.index, name='index'), # welcome page
    url(r'^api/v1/$', views.index, name='index'), # welcome page
    (r'^api/', include((v1_api.urls))), # model urls
    url(r'^docs/', include('docs.urls')), # docs pages
)
```

I'm providing a GUI for the API and I'd like buttons to link actual tastypie API commands, e.g. `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/?format=json`. If I have a standard django view, I can just type `<a href="{% url 'api.views.users'%}"` inside the .html file (api = app name, users = a view). How can I achieve this using tastypie?

Comment: Are you looking for this? [Reverse Resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) and [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

Comment: yes, but using tastypie which is an API generator. It generates all URLs internally...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by GUI? A standalone desktop application or a web front-end served by Django?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Swagger](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/)?

> Swagger is a specification and complete framework implementation for describing, producing, consuming, and visualizing RESTful web services.

And to connect it with Tastypie: [django-tastypie-swagger](https://github.com/concentricsky/django-tastypie-swagger)

Answer (score 0):

This is not very well documented, but you can see the view names in the [source code](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L297). So you can do stuff like:

```
{% url api_dispatch_list resource_name='user' api_name='v1' %}
{% url api_dispatch_detail resource_name='user' api_name='v1' pk=5 %}
```

[Here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/409) are more details.